# In my Surface Pro 8 doesn't work webcam

Tags: drivers, 22.04, webcam, camera, surface

I recently bought a [SP8]Surface Pro 8 and found the correct drivers and ways to operate the touchscreen and pen, display battery status, and other things.

An important thing to finish is the webcam. For the webcam I have not found any solution yet. Maybe some of you have some hints to play the web cam?
Thank you!

My linux distribution is Ubuntu 22.04

With Cheese i get:

```
cheese ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2220: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available. ** Message: 18:43:54.594: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: Nessun dispositivo trovato (No device found)   (cheese:102941): cheese-CRITICAL **: 18:43:54.604: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed  (cheese:102941): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:43:54.604: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
```

Comment: if you type `cheese` in command line do you get any notices/errors? if so add them to the question

Comment: @Rinzwind In my console i get it ->

```cheese
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2220: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
** Message: 18:43:54.594: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: Nessun dispositivo trovato (No device found)


(cheese:102941): cheese-CRITICAL **: 18:43:54.604: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:102941): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:43:54.604: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
```